# Dimmer switch not working

Tags: dimmer-switch

My chandelier has a dimmer switch and my lights suddenly are very dim. It does have a off and on switch also so I thought it was bad dimmer. I changed it and the same results. I did try to hook the hot straight to the chandelier wire and the lights were bright but it just won't work through the dimmer switch. It doesn't make sense but I know I'm missing something. Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the dimmer and the switch box?

Comment: Did the dimmer work before?  Any changes to the wiring?

Comment: Many dimmers need the live line voltage on 1 lead and the load going to the lamp if these are backwards on some lights they don’t work correctly. Some switch legs only 1 cable at the switch the white should be the hot to the switch and the black is the load to the switch. I have seen this several times because switch legs white is not neutral but should be hot.

Comment: What model # is the **new** dimmer? What type of bulbs - incandescent, fluorescent or LED? Have you changed any/all of the bulbs recently?